# Начал изучать java проблема с кодировкой

Tags: java, кодировка, netbeans

> import java.util.Scanner;

```
 Scanner sc1 = new Scanner(System.in);
```

При вводе латиницей все норм, а если на русском написать получается так

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Я так понимаю нужно вывод в консоль  System.out.print(); как то преобразовать, или на вводе сразу преобразовать

Answer (score 0):

Добавьте такую строку

```
System.setProperty("console.encoding","Cp866");
```

Или же пробуйте такую конструкцию должно сработать

```
PrintStream staream  = new PrintStream(System.out, false, "Cp866");
staream.println("Ваш текст");
```

Можете "плясать" как хотите, меняя ср866, на любую другую, например Windows-1251, пока неполучите ожидаемый результат!